# Is passing multiple files to `mix credo` supported?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, code-analysis, elixir-mix

I am trying to automate Elixir code analysis before each commit on staged files with [credo](https://github.com/rrrene/credo) in a Phoenix app, but it seems that credo takes into account only the first file of the list when running `mix credo file1.ex file2.exs file3.ex`.

Is this behavior wanted ? Support for multiple files input is planned ? Thanks in advance !

Elixir : `1.4.1`

Credo  : `0.6.1`

Phoenix : `1.2.1`

PS : I am using the default `.credo.exs` generated by `mix credo gen.config`

Comment: I guess only the author can answer whether "Support for multiple files input is planned".

Comment: Yes indeed, his answer : https://twitter.com/CaouiBachir/status/838772385419517952

I will link the issue to this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is intended (by the author himself : https://twitter.com/CaouiBachir/status/838772385419517952 )

This is the issue following this SO thread :
https://github.com/rrrene/credo/issues/332